# React loading unknown number of API calls with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The project I'm working on requires a lot of API calls to the backend server using `useApiGet`. Some components make several API calls (4 or 5), while others only make 1. I want to create a custom hook that can take an array of objects `{name, endpoint}` and return the API data. This is mostly intended to help with error handling.

useDataLoader.js

```js
const useDataLoader = (arrayOfEndpoints) => {
  let dataArray = []
  arrayOfEndpoints.forEach(endpoint => {
    const [data, error] = useApiGet(endpoint.path)
    if (error.res.status === 404 return <NotFound />
    dataArray.push({name: endpoint.name, data})
  }

  return dataArray
}
```

MyComponent.js

```js
import useDataLoader from ...

export default function MyComponent () {
  const [dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD] = useDataLoader([
    {name: dataA, path: endpointA}, 
    {name: dataB, path: endpointB}, 
    {name: dataC, path: endpointC}, 
    {name: dataD, path: endpointD}, 
  ])

  ...other stuff

  return (...)
}
```

`useDataLoader` should return an array of objects. The problem however is that `useApiGet` is also a hook and cannot be used inside a loop. What is an alternative way to do this?

The only other way I can think of this would be to return a `<NotFound />` after every single API call which would create an issue of lots of duplicate code and code complexity (`<NotFound />` could not be right after each API call because other hooks would be called conditionally). That would look like this:

```js
export default function MyComponent () {
  const [data: dataA, error: errorA] = useApiGet(endpointA)
  const [data: dataB, error: errorB] = useApiGet(endpointB)
  const [data: dataC, error: errorC] = useApiGet(endpointC)
  const [data: dataD, error: errorD] = useApiGet(endpointD)

  ...other stuff

  const errors = [errorA, errorB, errorC, errorD]
  errors.forEach(error => {if (error.res.status === 404 return <NotFound />})

  return (...)
}
```

This would need to be done for each component and would not be ideal.

My question is NOT "Why can't I use a React Hook in a loop?", which has been answered many times. This is understood. The question is "how can I make an indefinite number of API calls using this hook instead of writing a LOT of duplicate code?"

Comment: What do you mean by *"The problem however is that useApiGet is also a hook and cannot be used inside a the loop."*? Hooks can be used in loops, provided the loop always has the same number of iterations each time it's used in the same place in the same component instance. (That is, it can't have three loops in one render but six in another.) `DataLoader` has to be a hook, because it uses a hook (`useGetApi`). Hooks can only be used in components or other hooks.

Comment: (Note that since it's a hook, it should start with `use`: `useDataLoader`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: That sentence is sadly over-simplified, see [the details further down the page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation). What matters is consistent order and numbering of calls, which is why the details call out calls being made "conditionally." Using a loop isn't calling them "conditionally." Again: Provided the loop's number of iterations is constant, it's absolutely fine and in fact it's impossible for React to know whether you're doing `useGetApi()`, `useGetApi()`, `useGetApi()`, `useGetApi()` or `for (let n = 0; n < 4; ++n) { useGetApi(); }`

Comment: (Sadly, much the same sentence is also in the beta docs here: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-a-components-memory It's probably put that way because most uses of loops will in fact be mistakes, and they don't want to have to go into the deep explanation. :-| )

Comment: What is the purpose of `return <NotFound />` in your `forEach` callback? It just returns from the callback (and is promptly ignored by `forEach`, which doesn't use the callback return value for anything), it has no effect on what is returned by `DataLoader`.

Comment: What library are you using for `useApiGet()`? A quick search gives me [`api-client`](https://github.com/RightIntel/api-client#hooks) which also seems to have a [`useApiGetAll()`](https://github.com/RightIntel/api-client/tree/v3.2.1#hooks) hook that accepts an array.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm using SWR. There is no `useApiGetAll()` option

Comment: @wolf_math I don't see any `useApiGet()` hook in the [SWR documentation](//swr.vercel.app/docs) either. The only hook provided by SWR seems to be the [`useSWR()`](//swr.vercel.app/docs/api) hook.

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

To my mind, you're best off sticking with individual calls to `useGetApi`. That way, not only are you not violating the rules as described on [the page you linked in the comments](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) *(although see below, I think those are slightly over-stated for simplicity)*, but the code is very declarative and straightfoward. If you had `useGetApi` return the usual `[loading, data, error]` tuple, the code is;

```
const [aLoading, a, aError] = useGetApi("a");
const [bLoading, b, aError] = useGetApi("b");
const [cLoading, c, cerror] = useGetApi("c");
// ...
if (aError || bError || cError) {
    return <NotFound />;
}
```

then rendering `a` (for instance) is:

```
{aLoading ? <Loading /> : a}
```

**But**, the premise of your question is that you don't want to do that. And certainly it would be very easy to add a `d` to the above but forget to update the `if (aError || bError || cError)` condition. So the answer below suggests how you might do your data loader concept.

## Answer

As you say, the documentation says [not to run hooks in loops](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (including in [the beta documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/state-a-components-memory)). But this is an oversimplification to help people avoid getting themselves in trouble. The **real** issue is stated [later in the page](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation) of that first link:

> So how does React know which state corresponds to which useState call? The answer is that **React relies on the order in which Hooks are called.**

*(their emphasis)* followed by:

> As long as the order of the Hook calls is the same between renders, React can associate some local state with each of them. But what happens if we put a Hook call (for example, the `persistForm` effect) inside a condition?

As you can see, the real issue is that **the same hooks must be called in the same order** on every render. As long as your loop is unchanging — it calls the same hooks in the same order every time — there's no problem with using a loop. In fact, it's impossible for React to tell the difference between:

```
const [a, setA] = useState(0);
const [b, setB] = useState(0);
const [c, setC] = useState(0);
const [d, setD] = useState(0);
```

and

```
// Don't do this, it's just for illustration
const stuff = [];
for (let n = 0; n < 4; ++n) {
    stuff.push(useState(0));
}
```

Either way, `useState` is called four times. (That said, [I've asked the React documentation team](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/2492#issuecomment-1424017535) for input on this.)

With that in mind:

You haven't shown `useGetApi`, but the usual thing is for it to return a tuple (fixed-length array, like `useState` does) with three elements: a loading flag, the data (if it has it), or an error (if it has one). That is: `[loading, data, error]`. If `loading` is `false` and `error` is `null`, that means `data` is valid.

Assuming a structure like that for `useGetApi`, you could have `useDataLoader` load multiple items and aggregate loading flags and error states for you.

There are **lots** of ways to spin this.

One thing you could do is have `useDataLoader` return a count of the number of items that are loading, a count of the number of items with errors, and then an element for each call to `useGetApi` containing the array it returned. So instead of:

```
const [aLoading, a, aError] = useGetApi("a");
const [bLoading, b, bError] = useGetApi("b");
const [cLoading, c, cError] = useGetApi("c");
// ...
if (aError || bError || cError) {
    return <NotFound />;
}
// ...
```

you could do:

```
const [
    loadingCount,
    errorCount,
    [, a],   // Or [aLoading, a, aError]
    [, b],   // Or [bLoading, b, bError]
    [, c],   // Or [cLoading, c, cError]
] = useDataLoader("a", "b", "c");
// ...
if (errorCount > 0) {
    return <NotFound />;
}
if (loadingCount > 0) {
    return <Loading />;
}
// ...use `a`, `b`, and `c` here...
```

That gives your component the full picture, both aggregate and detail, so that if you wanted to handle the loading aspect of `a`, `b`, and `c` discretely, you could:

```
const [
    loadingCount,
    errorCount,
    [aLoading, a],
    [bLoading, b],
    [cLoading, c],
] = useDataLoader("a", "b", "c");
// ...
if (errorCount > 0) {
    return <NotFound />;
}
```

then rendering (say) `a`, we have the same thing we had with individual calls:

```
{aLoading ? <Loading /> : a}
```

Or if you know you **never** care about the individual loading flags or error messages, you could return just the counts and the data instead. For some reason, in my head, that would argue for a fixed number of elements: `[loadingCount, errorCount, dataArray]`:

```
const [
    loadingCount,
    errorCount,
    [ a, b, c],
] = useDataLoader("a", "b", "c");
// ...
if (errorCount > 0) {
    return <NotFound />;
}
// ...
if (loadingCount > 0) {
    return <Loading />;
}
// ...use `a`, `b`, and `c` here...
```

Here's a rough sketch (and ***only*** a rough sketch) of how `useDataLoader` might look if it provided the full details:

```
const useDataLoader = (...endpoints) => {
    let loadingCount = 0;
    let errorCount = 0;
    const dataArray = endpoints.map((endpoint) => {
        const apiResult = useGetApi(endpoint);
        const [loading, , error] = apiResult;
        if (loading) {
            ++loadingCount;
        }
        if (error) {
            ++errorCount;
        }
        return apiResult;
    });
    // Return the number of loading items, number of error items, and then
    // the `[loading, data, error]` arrays for each item in the arguments
    return [loadingCount, errorCount, ...dataArray];
};
```

Here's a live example. Again there are a dozen different was to spin this and I would probably never do it quite this way in reality, but you wanted a single "error" state, so... This loads three items via API calls, where each API call has a 1:10 chance of failing. It shows the items as they're loading, but switches to a single erorr state if any of them fail.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const useGetApi = (endpoint) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        // Add an artificial, varying delay
        delay(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000)).then(() =>
            fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com${endpoint}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    if (!res.ok) {
                        throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
                    }
                    // Make one in 10 calls fail, to test the error path
                    if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
                        throw new Error();
                    }
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then(setData)
                .catch(setError)
                .finally(() => setLoading(false))
        );
    }, []);

    // Fairly common pattern: loading flag, data, error
    return [loading, data, error];
};

const useDataLoader = (...endpoints) => {
    let loadingCount = 0;
    let errorCount = 0;
    const dataArray = endpoints.map((endpoint) => {
        const apiResult = useGetApi(endpoint);
        const [loading, , error] = apiResult;
        if (loading) {
            ++loadingCount;
        }
        if (error) {
            ++errorCount;
        }
        return apiResult;
    });
    // Return the number of loading items, number of error items, and then
    // the `[loading, data, error]` arrays for each item in the arguments
    return [loadingCount, errorCount, ...dataArray];
};

const Loading = () => <em>Loading...</em>;

const Example = () => {
    // prettier-ignore
    const [
        loadingCount,
        errorCount,
        [aLoading, a],
        [bLoading, b],
        [cLoading, c],
    ] = useDataLoader("/posts/1", "/posts/2", "/posts/3");
    const [ticker, setTicker] = useState(0);

    // This is just here to show re-rendering unrelated to the loading of
    // posts works just fine
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setTicker((t) => t + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);

    if (errorCount > 0) {
        return <div>Errors loading {errorCount} item(s)...</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <strong>Ticker</strong>: {ticker} (just to show state unrelated to the data loading)
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>A</strong>: {aLoading ? <Loading /> : a.title}
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>B</strong>: {bLoading ? <Loading /> : b.title}
            </div>
            <div>
                <strong>C</strong>: {cLoading ? <Loading /> : c.title}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div>Run several times, there's a 1:10 chance of an artificial API failure, and 3 API calls per run, so roughly one in three times you run it, you'll see an error.</div>
<hr>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```